# Initiating datepicker issue

Tags: javascript, datepicker

This is my js code:

```
function myfunction(custom){
        minDate = '';
        maxDate = '';
        initDatePicker('#startDate\\['+custom+'\\]', minDate, maxDate);
        initDatePicker('#endDate\\['+custom+'\\]', minDate, maxDate);
}
function initDatePicker(cls, minDate, maxDate, beforeshowday) {
    beforeshowday = beforeshowday == "1" ? beforeshowday : "0";
    $(cls).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
            if (beforeshowday == 0) {
                return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 || dt.getDay() == 3 || dt.getDay() == 4 || dt.getDay() == 5, ""];
            }
            else {
                return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
            }
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: maxDate,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        date: $(cls).val(),
        current: $(cls).val(),
        starts: 1,
        onBeforeShow: function() {
            $(cls).DatePickerSetDate($(cls).val(), true);
        },
        onChange: function(formated) {
            $(cls).val(formated);
            $(cls).DatePickerHide();
        }

    })
            .attr("readonly", "readonly");

}
```

When i called the myfunction function it does not initiate my datepicker. What am i doing wrong ? Is this because of the type of the ID ? thx in advance

Comment: Does anything show up in the console? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Are you doing it after the DOM is loaded and the elements exists? Are you getting any error messages in your console?

Comment: nothing in the console

Comment: @FrankerZ after the dom is loaded I created the elements

Comment: `console.log(cls)` and make sure that you can access those elements in your local console.

Comment: the result of the console.log(cls) is #startDate\[1\] and #endDate\[1\]

Comment: This is how it looks like the created input: <input name="startDate[1]" id="startDate[1]" value="2015-06-02" readonly="" class="forDatePicker hasDatepicker" size="14" onchange="changeEndDate(1); calculateDaysDuration('@[1]', 1); " type="text">

Answer (score 0):

If you have ID for the text box then pass that one as first parameter of element. Like below code

```
initDatePicker('#startDate', minDate, maxDate);
```

As you said in comment (#startDate[1] and #endDate[1]...), you can't use more than one ID in a single page. If you have more than one datepicker in a page then please use :eq function. See example below.

```
initDatePicker('[name="startDate"]:eq('+ custom +')', minDate, maxDate);
initDatePicker('[name="endDate"]:eq('+ custom +')', minDate, maxDate);
```

Thanks

Comment: I have startDate[0], startDate[1], startDate[2].... The eq function does not work for me:(

Comment: Have you tried with name of text boxes ? and remove the ID from text box

Comment: this fiddle doesn't show any datepicker when i clicked on in the inputs

Comment: Then I think its problem with you browser versions.. Please check with other systems or browsers.. Here I have checked with 3 systems every where its working perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79425/discussion-between-rahul-radhakrishnan-and-jozsef-naghi).